# Python append to return dict instead of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

The append below is working but it is return a list instead of a dict. So when I tried the extract the key/value with tag.items() it is telling me that there's a

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expect 2, got 1)

This is the correct error message as it a list as all_tags.append creates a list. How do I return it as a dict?

```
tags = get_all_tags(client_tags)

for tag in tags:
    tag_key, tag_value = tag.items()
```

...

```
def get_all_tags(client_tags):

    for tag_key, tag_value in client_tags.items():
        if re.match(TAG_KEY_PATTERN, tag_key):
           all_tags.append({tag_key: tag_value})

    return all_tags
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't make it a `list` of `dict`s to start with, just make a `dict` in the first place:

```
def get_all_tags(client_tags):
    all_tags = {}
    for tag_key, tag_value in client_tags.items():
        if re.match(TAG_KEY_PATTERN, tag_key):
           all_tags[tag_key] = tag_value

    return all_tags
```

Or as a one-liner using a `dict` comprehension:

```
def get_all_tags(client_tags):
    return {k: v for k, v in client_tags.items() if re.match(TAG_KEY_PATTERN, k)}
```

Either way, your loop to use it would be:

```
for tag_key, tag_value in tags.items():
    ...
```

Comment: +1 We have very similar thought processes :) Or rather, Python is elegant enough to have certain clear ways of doing things :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `tag.items()` returns a `dict_items` instance (one object not a tuple). The reasons why you are confused is because when you do a foreach over it you can extract them as tuples, but the reason is because `dict_item` is an iterable which yields tuples for each iteration.

Instead of `all_tags.append({tag_key: tag_value})` you might want to append a tuple like `all_tags.append((tag_key, tag_value))`.

Comment: This works but it is returning a list. i.e 'list' object has no attributes 'items'

Comment: @munchine, that's the point, it's no longer a dict, you don't need to call `items()`

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the function to this:

```
def get_all_tags(client_tags):
    all_tags = {}
    for tag_key, tag_value in client_tags.items():
       if re.match(TAG_KEY_PATTERN, tag_key):
           all_tags[tag_key] = tag_value

    return all_tags
```

You can even do dictionary comprehension:

```
def get_all_tags(client_tags):
    return {tag_key: tag_value for tag_key, tag_value in client_tags if re.match(TAG_KEY_PATTERN, tag_key)}
```